# custom Zend Form Element that combines 2 existing elements

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I noticed that I'm using the `Element_Checkbox` and `Element_Text` together a lot in my project. Is there a way to combine them together into a single element so that I can just do something like:

```
new Zend_Form_Element_Combo
```

I tried like at the documentation but I feel they complicate it a lot. I just want to bundle the 2 elements together.

Comment: Try these two links: [Complex custom elements in Zend_Form | CodeUtopia](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/10/23/complex-custom-elements-in-zend_form/) and [Creating composite elements - phly, boy, phly](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/217-Creating-composite-elements.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish, you'll either what to just simply make a [subform](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.subforms) or a composite element. There is a great [Zend Cast](http://www.zendcasts.com/writing-composite-zend_form-elements/2010/03/) on the subject of composite elements.